# wkhtmltoimage doesn't work with websnap/imgkit on CentOs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltoimage, imgkit

Here is action to generate png that works in development environment.

```
  def action
    html = "<b>test</b>"
    snap = IMGKit.new(html, :'crop-h' => 750, :'crop-h' => 290, quality: 50)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.png { send_data snap.to_img(:png) }
    end
  end
```

But on CentOS (production) server it generates only blank file.
Note that this code WORKS from rails console on production server, but it does not work inside the controller action.

```
  html = "<b>test</b>"
  snap = IMGKit.new(html, :'crop-h' => 750, :'crop-h' => 290, quality: 50)
```

Is it a threading issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow it worked:

```
 -    respond_to do |format|
 -      format.png { send_data snap.to_img(:png) }
 -    end
 +    send_data snap.to_img(:jpg)
```

Note that in my case there was no difference which format to use, lossy .jpg or lossless .png